# Jenkins How to allocate whole node per one specific job

Tags: jenkins

I'm vary newbie in Jenkins.

I have some specific job and some nodes with different count of executors in each.

I need to allocate for specific job whole compute node. 
I mean that when my specific job build in a node another executors will stop or something lock. Only one executor work for build specific job.

May be I can do parallel build on whole node executors in one moment ? 
But how it can do ?

Or may be is some way to loc all node memory or something else ?

How I can get it ?
I have more problems to stop jenkins and install new plugins. 
Ideally to make it without plugins.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot do this.  The closest you can get is to allocate one executor per node.  This means, of course, you will never be able to run jobs in parallel on that node.